# How to link cusparse using CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cuda, cmake

How can I add the `cusparse` library from CUDA in a `CMakeLists.txt`-file, such that the `nvcc` compiler includes it automatically with `-lcusparse`? I already added the line

```
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS};-lcusparse)
```

in `CMakeLists.txt` with no success. It looks like I'm missing something, because Nsight throws the error

```
undefined reference to 'cusparseDestroyMatDescr'.
```

Although when I exclude this line where `cusparseDestroyMatDescr` is called via commenting it, the Nsight project builds with no error, even with these three lines of code included

```
cusparseStatus_t status;
cusparseHandle_t handle=0;
cusparseMatDescr_t descr=0;
```

So it looks like it knows what `cusparseStatus_t` and so on is, but it does not know what `cusparseDestroyMatDescr` is.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way in CMake to link a library is using
`target_link_libraries( target library )`.

If you use [FindCUDA](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/FindCUDA.html) to locate the CUDA installation, the variable `CUDA_cusparse_LIBRARY` will be defined. Thus, all you need to do is

```
target_link_libraries( target ${CUDA_cusparse_LIBRARY} )
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the [CMake CUDAToolkit](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDAToolkit.html#cuda-toolkit-cusparse) package, which is available with CMake 3.17 and newer:

```
find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)
...
target_link_libraries(target CUDA::cusparse)
```